# Unknown internet traffic

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

My Internet device (a USB dongle) shows Internet speed very good. But actually, when I browse and surf websites, they all seem to load very slow. Even if none of sites are loading, all stopped, the device will still show much high download and upload speeds. It seems there's always something hidden traffic running on the background which I can't see. What it could be?

How  can I know every single program using my Internet bandwidth? Is there any program for it?

Comment: Installing wireshark may help

Comment: also u can download a port scaners prgrams to understand all of the established connectios and find something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EtherApe is a graphical network monitor modeled after etherman. it displays network activity graphically, showing active hosts as circles of varying size, and traffic among them as lines of varying width.

It features link layer, ip and TCP modes, color-color coded protocols display, Ethernet, FDDI, Token Ring, ISDN, PPP and SLIP devices. It can filter traffic to be shown, and can read traffic from a file as well as live from the network. You can Download it from The Software Center.

Run it with Sudo

```
sudo etherape
```

[image]

Comment: Nice.is this program can be download from repositories? or download from source?

Comment: From the repositories   --  Software Center, or command line --- sudo apt-get install etherape ----. There are Lots of options so be sure to read the Help Guide

Comment: Awesome! I found the culprit. It is Mozilla Sync. Great tool. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I know every single program using my Internet bandwidth? Is
>   there any program for it?

You can use `nethogs` to acomplish this, it monitors bandwitdth per process so it's more accurate than check per application

it's in the repositories, so you can install it by tipyng:

> apt-get install nethogs

and then you can use it by tipyng:

> sudo nethogs DEVICE

where `DEVICE` can be `eth0` for ethernet or `wlan0` for wireless connection